# android getInputType in JAVA code

Tags: java, android

I defined a EditText in XML with attribute **android:inputType="numberSigned"**, so, when I try to get it in Java Code like:

> `int type = mEditText.getInputType();`
>   `switch(type){`
>   `case InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_SIGNED:`
>   `//do when I get EditText defined with 'numberSinged'`
>   `//do something`
>   `break;`
>   `}`

But, It doesn't work for me. So I try to check Android source code, `TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_SIGNED=4096`. When I try to print `println(mEditText.getInputType())`,it turns to be `4098`. And I can't find any variable equals `4098`. 
Can anybody tell me the reason?

*I'm not good at English, may you can understand me! Thanks!*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there can be multiple flags assigned to inputType. To find out if a flag is set or not, use the bitwise AND (`&`) operator:

```
int type = mEditText.getInputType();
if((type & InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_SIGNED) > 0)
{
    // your stuff here
}
```

I guess, the usage of `switch` case is not possible here.

Comment: it has an error: The operator & is undefined for the argument type(s) int, boolean. One more question, is there any variable stands for 4098? just like 'TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_SIGNED'?

Comment: yes, It works! Thank you very much! But why I execute `println(mEditText.getInputType())`,the result is 4098 instead of 4096?

Comment: because there are multiple flags present.

Answer (score 0):

`TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_SIGNED` Constant Value: 4096 (0x00001000) .

get more information [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputType.html#TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_SIGNED)

Comment: Why I print `mEditText.getInputType()` is 4098? if I have defined 'android:inputType="numberSigned"', I think it should to be TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_SIGNED(4096), anything I missed?

Comment: Because according to the documentation, numberSigned correspond to the combination of TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_SIGNED, with values 2 and 4096, respectively.